# jQuery and CSS causing text to move oddly after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sPUDL/) which scrolls a box down and back up, however the text "hide" and "show" move about a bit when the animation has finished. I have tried a few different things but cannot get it to scroll correctly.

```
$('a#mainToggle').click(function(){
    if ($('a#mainToggle').hasClass("down")) {
        $('a#mainToggle').removeClass("down");
        $('a#mainToggle').addClass("up");

        $('#contentCollapse').stop(true, true).animate({height: '30px'},1000,function(){
                $('#contentCollapse').css("display", "none");
                $('a#mainToggle').addClass("hangDown");
        });
        $('a#mainToggle span').text("Show");
        $('#mainToggle em').html("<img src='img/show.gif' />");
    } // end if
    else{
        $('#contentCollapse').css("display", "block");
        curHeight = $('#contentCollapse').height();
        $('a#mainToggle').removeClass("hangDown");
        autoHeight = $('#contentCollapse').css('height', 'auto').height();
        autoHeight = autoHeight + 15;
        $('#contentCollapse').height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000,function(){
            $('a#mainToggle').addClass("down");
            $('a#mainToggle').removeClass("up");
            $('a#mainToggle span').text("Hide");
            $('#mainToggle em').html("<img src='img/hide.gif' />");
        });
    } // end else
});
```

Comment: The show/hide movement is because of the padding and margin on the elements above it.

Comment: Your padding is causing the issue.. remove padding from hangDown

Comment: okay thanks, hangDown is removed when it comes back down, so it is moving after callback from moving down